# Spring Boot - What is the new Property Name for `management.endpoint.env.post.enabled`

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to enable the use of POST requests via Spring Boot Actuator using `spring-boot-starter-parent` with version `2.3.2.RELEASE` and the latest `2.4.3` release.

I'm currently getting a 405 error response with "Method Not Allowed" and a message of "Request Method 'POST' not supported". From some googling it looks like Spring Boot v2.2.4 introduced the `management.endpoint.env.post.enabled` which needed to be set to `true` to allow posts but that no longer seems to be recognized in Spring Boot 2.3.2. Has this property been renamed?

Comment: What's the actuator endpoint you're trying to reach with your post request?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/actuator/env      e.g: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  http://localhost:8080/actuator/env -d property=value

Comment: This property is from [spring cloud](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/multi/multi__appendix_compendium_of_configuration_properties.html). Do you use it in your project?

Comment: yes, I'm using Spring Cloud Stream and trying to dynamically change a property on a binding